# Change buddy status on contact app in Android

Tags: android, listview, status, contacts

I am working on a buddy list for my program. What I have now is a `ListView` with all the users that the server sends to me. I display name and contact address. What I need also is to display  whether the user is online or offline in real time.

When I populate the `ListView` for first time  I have an `ArrayList` with all the users and their status, so I can show all their information. My problem comes when the users come and go offline. They are still in the list but their status must change.

I've been searching for solutions on the web. The one that I've found says that I should clear the `ArrayList` first, then invalidate `ListView` to redraw, then add new data to the ArrayList and then notify my adapter to populate the `ListView` again  with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I think that it could be a slow solution because I could have 1000 contacts and they could change the status frequently.

Is there any other solution for doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have an `ArrayList<Contact>` where Contact is a custom class that that has the contact private params (name, uri and status). When a user changes its status, I search it in the array and change its status.

Then I pass the new `ArrayList<Contact>` to my custom BaseAdapter and then do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. There is no need to invalidate the `ListView` first.